# d3: Make tick marks on d3.svg.axis draggable?

Tags: d3.js

I'd like to repurpose d3.svg.axis for a use that would require the tick marks to be large and draggable:

[image: axis]

For example, in the above screenshot of [the axis whose code is here](http://livecoding.io/5137615), I'd like the mouse to change to the four-cornered shape when you hover over either the 25 or 69, and then be able to drag the tick marks left and right by hold-clicking the mouse.

I can see the `<svg>` code auto-generated by d3 produces a separate `<line>` element for each tick whose class is "tick":

[image: axis code]

So I assume there is a way to target those elements and make them respond to dragging, but I'm unclear how to do it.  And of course, the line element should not be draggable anywhere, but should only slide left and right along the horizontal axis, and cannot be moved beyond the beginning and ending ticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working: [livecoding.io example](http://livecoding.io/5140513)

And here the relevant code, not particularly clean but working:

```
var w = h = 600;
var padding = 20;
var svg = d3.select("svg").attr("width", w).attr("height", h);

var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
             .domain([0, 100])
             .range([padding, w - padding * 2]);

var sharedAxis = function() {
  return d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(xScale)
            .tickValues([19,69])
            .tickSize(50);
}

var downAxis = sharedAxis()
            .orient("bottom");

var upAxis = sharedAxis()
            .orient("top");

var addPlayer = function(playerAxis) {
  svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "axis")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (100) + ")")
   .call(playerAxis);
}


addPlayer(downAxis);
addPlayer(upAxis);

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag", dragmove);

function dragmove(d) {
  // move it
  var curX = d3.select(this).attr("transform").match(/\(([^,]+),/)[1];
  var newX = Math.max(xScale.range()[0], d3.event.x);
  newX = Math.min(xScale.range()[1], newX);
  var newTransform = d3.select(this).attr("transform").replace(/\([^,]+,/, "(" + newX + ",");
  d3.select(this).attr("transform", newTransform);
  // update text
  d3.select(this).select("text").text(parseInt(xScale.invert(newX)));
}

var allTicks = d3.selectAll(".axis g").call(drag);
```